# Android- programmatically restrict which apps can be run

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I'm building an app that needs to restrict which apps can be run along with it.

In example, when my app is running (foreground or background) I can allow user  to run only GoogleMaps, and MusicPlayer.

I've read a bit about [`Device Policy Controller`](https://developers.google.com/android/work/build-dpc) and creating profiles, and up to some point it seems to have the feature I need, but it is designed for enterprise deployment, and user needs to encrypt their phone beforehand. Is creating personalized profiles a way to go?

My other idea was to run a service that each few milliseconds check if there is any forbidden app running and finish it, but it seems to be not robust.

Is there any way of handling this problem programmatically?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this; e.g. you could use an accessibility service to start your app in front of the other app. What is the use case though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that Device Policy Controller is a right thing for you. 
And you can't just kill other apps without root.

So some kind of user-friendly way to achieve the goal is to check running apps list with [ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses()) and to notify user that he has to finish particular apps to use your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess it would be ok when starting my app, but I need a bit more. I have to prevent a situantion in which my app is running and then user tries to start one of the forbidden apps. Is there a way to do that? On tablets there are user profiles which 'hide' apps that are not allowed- this is an effect I would like to obtain. Can something like that be done on any mobile device and can it be done by an app?

Comment: It seems that there is no other way. But on Android 5.0+ you have to use `UsageStatsManager` instead of `ActivityManager`.